# TKinter - AttributeError when trying to destroy a button

Tags: python, tkinter

Greetings Stack Overflowers!

Please note that I'm a novice and I'm just learning.

I'm having the following error : `AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'button_draw'`

The main logic where the issue seems to be is located in `start_game_event`. Basically if the `game_type` is `with draw`, then the button must be created. However, if a new game is made based on the current windows and the button still exists, I want it to be removed. I'm not sure if there's another way to go about it, for instance regenerating the main frame completely but that's where I'm standing.

Here's the code :

```
from tkinter import Button, E, Frame, IntVar, Label, LEFT, messagebox, N, NE, Radiobutton, RIGHT, S, SW, StringVar, Tk, Toplevel, W

class DominoWindow(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.nb_players_var = None
        self.type_partie = None

        self.title('Jeu de Pydomino!')
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.frame_player_north = Frame(self)
        self.frame_player_west = Frame(self)
        self.frame_table = Frame(self, borderwidth=2)
        self.frame_player_est = Frame(self)
        self.frame_current_player = Frame(self)

        self.frame_player_north.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.frame_player_west.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.frame_table.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.frame_player_est.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.frame_current_player.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.label_name_player_north = Label(self.frame_player_north)
        self.label_name_player_north.grid(row=0)
        self.label_hand_player_north = Label(self.frame_player_north)
        self.label_hand_player_north.grid(row=1)

        self.label_name_player_west = Label(self.frame_player_west)
        self.label_name_player_west.grid(row=0)
        self.label_hand_player_west = Label(self.frame_player_west)
        self.label_hand_player_west.grid(row=1)

        self.label_table = Label(self.frame_table, height=8, width=100)
        self.label_table.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.label_name_player_east = Label(self.frame_player_est)
        self.label_name_player_east.grid(row=0)
        self.label_hand_player_east = Label(self.frame_player_est)
        self.label_hand_player_east.grid(row=1)

        self.label_name_current_player = Label(self.frame_current_player)
        self.label_name_current_player.grid(row=1)
        self.frame_hand_current_player = Frame(self.frame_current_player)

        self.button_quit = Button(self, text="Quitter", command=self.quit_party_event)
        self.button_quit.grid(row=3, column=2)

        self.button_new_game = Button(self, text="Nouvelle partie", command=self.introduction_game)
        self.button_new_game.grid(row=2, column=2)

        self.introduction_game()

    def show(self):

        if self.nb_players_var.get() == 2:
            self.label_name_player_north.config(text="Player 0")
            self.label_hand_player_north.config(text="[|]" * 6) #len(self.partie.donnes[self.partie.tour+1]))

            self.label_table.config(text="VARIABLE_TABLE")
            self.label_name_current_player.config(text="Player Current")

            self.label_name_player_east.config(text="")
            self.label_hand_player_east.config(text="")
            self.label_name_player_west.config(text="")
            self.label_hand_player_west.config(text="")

        elif self.nb_players_var.get() == 3:
            self.label_name_player_north.config(text="Player 0")
            self.label_hand_player_north.config(text="[|]" * 6) #len(partie.Partie.donnes[partie.tour+1]))

            self.label_name_player_east.config(text="Player 1")
            self.label_hand_player_east.config(text="[|]\n" * 6) #len(self.partie.donnes[self.partie.tour+2]))

            self.label_table.config(text="VARIABLE DU PLATEAU")
            self.label_name_current_player.config(text="Player Current")

            self.label_name_player_west.config(text="")
            self.label_hand_player_west.config(text="")

        elif self.nb_players_var.get() == 4:
            self.label_name_player_north.config(text="Player 0")
            self.label_hand_player_north.config(text="[|]" * 6) #len(self.partie.donnes[self.partie.tour+1]))

            self.label_name_player_east.config(text="Player 1")
            self.label_hand_player_east.config(text="[|]\n" * 6) #len(self.partie.donnes[self.partie.tour+2]))

            self.label_name_player_west.config(text="Player 3")
            self.label_hand_player_west.config(text="[|]\n" * 6) #len(self.partie.donnes[self.partir.tour+3]))

            self.label_table.config(text="VARIABLE_DU_PLATEAU")
            self.label_name_current_player.config(text="Player Current")

    def introduction_game(self):
        self.introduction_window_game = Toplevel(self, height=200, width=500)
        self.introduction_window_game.title("Choose your game settings!")
        self.introduction_window_game._root().lift()
        self.nb_players_var = IntVar()
        self.type_partie = StringVar()
        # Label(self.introduction_window_game, text="Choose your game settings!").pack()
        Label(self.introduction_window_game, text="\nWhat kind of game do you want?").pack()
        Radiobutton(self.introduction_window_game, text="Game without draw",
                    variable=self.type_partie, value="without draw").pack(anchor=W)
        Radiobutton(self.introduction_window_game, text="Game with draw",
                    variable=self.type_partie, value="with draw").pack(anchor=W)

        Label(self.introduction_window_game, text="\nCombien de Players voulez-vous?").pack()
        Radiobutton(self.introduction_window_game, text="2 Players",
                    variable=self.nb_players_var, value=2).pack(anchor=W)
        Radiobutton(self.introduction_window_game, text="3 Players",
                    variable=self.nb_players_var, value=3).pack(anchor=W)
        Radiobutton(self.introduction_window_game, text="4 Players",
                    variable=self.nb_players_var, value=4).pack(anchor=W)

        Button(self.introduction_window_game, text="Quit",
               command=self.quit_party_event).pack(side=RIGHT)
        Button(self.introduction_window_game, text="Ok",
               command=self.start_game_event).pack(side=RIGHT)

    def start_game_event(self):
        result = messagebox.askokcancel("Paramètres de partie",
                                        f"Vous avez choisi {self.nb_players_var.get()} Players et "
                                        f"le type de partie {self.type_partie.get()}."
                                        f"\nEst-ce exact?", icon='warning')
        if result == True:
            self.start_game()
            self.show()
            self.introduction_window_game.destroy()
            if self.type_partie.get() == "with draw":
                self.button_draw = Button(self, text="Draw", command=self.button_to_draw)
                self.button_draw.grid(row=3, column=0)
            else:
                self.button_draw.grid_remove()
                self.destroy

    def quit_party_event(self):
        result = messagebox.askokcancel("Quit the game.", "Are you sur?", icon='warning')
        if result == True:
            self.destroy()

    def button_to_draw(self):
        print("Function test. You drew a domino!")

    def message_fin_de_partie(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DominoWindow().mainloop()
```

The error is located here : `self.button_draw.grid_remove()`

Thank you and I hope it is all clear.

Edited : Removed dependency and adjusted the variable name. Mistype.

Comment: Your error claims it's on `draw_button`, not `button_draw`. Somewhere in code you haven't shown us, you're trying to reference `draw_button`. Also, you've posted way too much code. Please try to condense it down to a [mcve].

Comment: There is no `draw_button` in this code. The code is also way too long to be a [mcve]. Please reduce it, and if possible get rid of the pydomino dependency as well.

Comment: Code has been adjusted and the dependency has been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start by saying I commented out the line `self.start_game()` as the `start_game` method doesn't exist.  I'll also add that to reproduce the problem I started the app and then chose to start a game without draw with any number of players.

Ultimately it's possible to do what you appear to want: i.e. not always have the 'Draw' button.  What I would do would be to add the line `self.button_draw = None` somewhere within `__init__`().  This ensures that your window always has a `button_draw` attribute, and hence gets rid of the `AttributeError` about this attribute.

Next, you will need to adjust the lower `if` statement within `start_game_event()` to remove the 'Draw' button from the grid if it has been created:

```
        if self.type_partie.get() == "with draw":
            self.button_draw = Button(self, text="Draw", command=self.button_to_draw)
            self.button_draw.grid(row=3, column=0)
        elif self.button_draw is not None:
            self.button_draw.grid_remove()
            self.button_draw.destroy()
            self.button_draw = None
```

I've replaced the `else` with `elif` and the condition that `self.button_draw` isn't `None`: we can't remove the 'Draw' button if there's no button to remove.

Note also that I replaced the line `self.destroy` with `self.button_draw.destroy()`: the former would have closed your app had you called the method but as you didn't call `self.desroy` it did nothing.  Also, once the button has been destroyed we can set `self.button_draw` back to `None` to signify we have no 'Draw' button.

In a similar vein, if the 'Draw' button exists and you start another game with draw, you'll have two buttons in your window.  You'll only see one because one will be on top of the other.  However, as you only keep a reference to one button, you'll only be able to delete one of these two buttons.  I'll leave it up to you to make a similar modification to your code to only add the button if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Thank you Luke! I followed your guide lines and managed to make it work as intended. The `self.destroy` was present only to destroy the window popup that was present. It was a necessary evil. All in all, thank you. It works as intended.